# Android WiFi beacon timestamp

Tags: timestamp, wifi, android-wireless

I am trying to read the transmitted beacons by an access point, Android documentation provides less information about the beacons' fields that we can read. For example `Scanresult.timestamp` means according to Android documentation "Time Synchronization Function (tsf) timestamp in microseconds when this result was last seen".

So this is so ambiguous for me, could anybody explained what does this means? Is it the time that the access point broadcast the beacons or the time when the mobile get the beacon?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is going to be very useful, according to [this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61128) this time is actually when device last saw given AP.